# Changing Audio Volume using FFmpeg Android

Tags: android, cmd, ffmpeg, wav, volume

As I have understood, the only way to change `FFmpeg` volume is to do it throught a  `command line`.

This is what should change the volume of the audio :

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -filter:a "volume=1.5" output.wav
```

Now I have used `FFmpeg` with command line before and it looked like this and gave me no errors:

```
    String[] cmd = { "-i" , pcmtowavTempFile.toString(), "-i", mp3towavTempFile.toString(), "-filter_complex", "amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=3", combinedwavTempFile.toString()};
    ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String message) {                
            super.onSuccess(message);
            encodeWavToAAC();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(String message) {
            super.onFailure(message);
            onError(message);
        }
    });
```

But If I try to do it with audio volume in the same method, it just ignores it :

```
    String[] cmd = { "-i" , pcmtowavTempFile.toString(),  "-filter:a", "volume=1.3", pcmtowavTempFile.toString()};
    ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String message) {
            super.onSuccess(message);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(String message) {
            super.onFailure(message);

        }
    });
```

I get neither, no `success or error message` with the last volume change method.

Since the volume is there between `" "`, I tried adding this :

```
String[] cmd = { "-i" , pcmtowavTempFile.toString(),  "-filter:a", "\"volume=1.3\"", pcmtowavTempFile.toString()};
```

But the app started crashing after adding this line.

Comment: What is the exception that you get after adding the last line?

Comment: @RamiJemli It just crashes without giving me anything, I tried debugging it to get an exception but I got the same result - nothing.

Comment: @RamiJemli and I can be sure that it is cause by that because when I remove it, it does not crash. Or I just don't know how to look for command line errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here was that FFmpeg does NOT perform in-place editing which means that I can not overwrite the same `File`. I tried overwriting by adding command `"-y"` but that did not also work because of that same rule.

So the solution was to create a new `File` as output `File`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try using this library instead with the same command. It uses the latest FFmpeg.

https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android

```
FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
if (ffmpeg.isSupported()) {
   // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
   String[] cmd= {"-i", pcmtowavTempFile.toString(), "-af", "volume=1.3", pcmtowavTempFile.toString()};
   ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {}

        @Override
        public void onProgress(String message) {}

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String message) {}

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String message) {}

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {}

    });
} else {
  // ffmpeg is not supported
}
```

Comment: Since the first command is running perfectly I dought that FFmpeg is not supported

Comment: And I initialize the ffmpeg the same way

Comment: yes but this is the only library that has the latest compiled FFMpeg version as far as i know. It's worth the try.

Comment: I am sorry that I forgot to mention but im using the same FFmpeg library

Comment: The only thing that could be wrong here is the way I write the command, so either something to do with the volume or i dont know

Comment: I got it to work. Please check the command in my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry my connection is really slow here but now it works with `onStart` but `onSuccess` and `onFailure` still print nothing

Comment: I see. but what about the output file. Did you try opening it?

Comment: And I get the same result when adding `"\"volume=2.5\""``. By the way, thank you a lot for the help, even if you have no more ideas then at least something is already working. Also I tried opening the output file and there is no change in volume.

Comment: "-af", "volume=1.3"

Comment: and try 5 instead of 1.3

Comment: I did try all of them but still.. `onStart` gives me a print but it never gets to `onSuccess` or `onFailure`

Comment: okey, did you check the content of pcmtowavTempFile.toString() and pcmtowavTempFile.toString()

Comment: is pcmtowavTempFile of type File?

Comment: `pcmtowavTempFile = new File(context.getFilesDir()+ Common.TEMP_LOCAL_DIR + "/" + "_pcm.wav")` .. so yeah

Comment: I would love to accept your answer for all the hard work you did but since it is not answered I sadly cannot do that, so I upvoted your answers. I did get an error message and make a new thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983399/changing-audio-volume-using-ffmpeg-android-error

Comment: No problem. Sorry that i couldn't help.

Comment: It might be of interest to you, I posted what was the mistake in this case